# Full GC in G1 GC

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, g1gc, jstat

Jstat tool gives stats regarding young gc time and full gc time along with other information. As far as I know, Full GC in G1 GC consists of following phases :

1) Concurrent Marking (not Stop the world)

2) Remarking (Stop the world)

3) Reclaimation of empty regions (Stop the world)

4) Reclaimation of partially empty old regions through mixed gc (Happens over the time)

Now, I want to know jstat full gc time measures time for which of the phases ?
If Phase 1 and 2 are not considered for full gc time measurement then, why is full gc time more compared to young gc? Because, just phase 2 and 3 themselves seem to be lightweight phases.

Also, mixed gc happens over next few young gc. So, young gc time would increase for next few young gc after a full gc. Am I right in assuming this?

I have just started learning about working of G1 GC